# Removing empty entries with webpack

Tags: webpack

For example, I've got the following entry:

```
webpackJsonp([0,3],[
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    'use strict';

    __webpack_require__(1);

    __webpack_require__(6);

/***/ },
/* 1 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    'use strict';

    __webpack_require__(2);

/***/ },
/* 2 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    // removed by extract-text-webpack-plugin

/***/ },
/* 3 */,
/* 4 */,
/* 5 */,
/* 6 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    "use strict";

/***/ }
]);
```

As you can see this entry is doing nothing. Is it possible to tell webpack to remove this entry (because it's empty)?

Comment: 1 year and 4 months later, it seems that webpack still doesn't have an option to disable the webpack bootstrap code.

Comment: And 5 more months.

Comment: and 6 more months...